# Which 20th century male philosopher contended that creating and composing gets increasingly difficult, as time progresses?

Tags: reference-request

I can't remember where, but I stumbled on this quotation in some print book on postmodernism or 20th century music, written in English because I can't read any other language. The author was a European male, but I can't remember if he wrote that quote originally in English. If I recall, this quotation was first published after 1950.

He asseverated that by the 21th century, any idea or concept that's possible has been created, and that anything that can be said has been said.  As time moves forward, it gets harder to compose any novelty, because you'll just be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: The number of unsolved problems in mathematics has been increasing over time, as has the number of mathematicians (and mathematicians, by definition, do original, creative work).  Not only has mathematics yet to find an end to new ideas, the rate at which new ideas are being discovered is increasing.  Other creative fields are even less constrained than mathematics.

Comment: Richard Feynman who discribed In his *Chracter of Physical law* science as "the art of guessing" ends his book by ruminations about how "perpetual novelty" is not realistic, the main interesting things may have already been discovered and there is only boredom lying ahead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This does not answer your question. So don’t read it unless you think you might be interested in related thoughts and especially opinions. It’s a rant.

Somewhat ironically, what you are paraphrasing is not a new concept. As someone finally bothered to record on a scroll for posterity, 2,500 years ago, “There’s nothing new under the sun.”

I was amazed to find out how much “original research” is based on ignorance of what’s been done, or a special case of a clear theory, with no reference to said theory. The longer I live, the more I realize, “That is not a new concept” about things I hear contemporaneously, things I thought of long ago and thought were original, supposedly original things I read before and realize were done long before.  A professor half-jokingly told me that one of the secrets to good research is easily forgetting where you heard something. As things become more pc, this trend to reward creativity at the expense of knowing anything increases.

Education and the world could be improved by more effort to learn past wisdom. There is a strong tendency to be enamored with the latest and greatest in psychology for example, when research shows church attendance and the wisdom of the ages is probably more helpful. I just started reading the Bible this year, and I am amazed at the wisdom and storytelling. I was told this book, the most popular book in world history, was goofy and superstitious and silly and nonsensical etc. Just one quick example, the latest: “When someone wrongs you, pay attention to yourself.” I could write a page on how valuable that is (those are the times we don’t do so and make mistakes, those are the times with the most unhealthy thinking and suffer unconsciously, and several other things). One day some psychologist will discover it and write an article in the latest journal and everyone will think its new, and it will be forgotten ten years later, except by people who seek ancient wisdom.

Wr could discover truly new things much faster if more people knew what previous people had discovered. This is not an argument to innovate slowly.

We need to pass on knowledge and wisdom and lessons, in addition to creativity. And it doesn’t just apply to the most soft sciences. There is a mountain of brilliance in economics and applied mathematics and operations management and human resources and organizational structure and teaching and learning that few know and many will rediscover. We need more ScD’s and fewer PhD’s. Not none, but certainly less. And harder and fewer undergrads. I saw some entrance tests for a state school from many decades ago, almost nobody would pass them now.

Ecclesiastes 1

> 9 What has been will be again,
> what has been done will be done again;
> there is nothing new under the sun.
> 10 Is there anything of which one can say,
> “Look! This is something new”?
> It was here already, long ago;
> it was here before our time.
> 11 No one remembers the former generations,
> and even those yet to come
> will not be remembered
> by those who follow them.

Comment: 2500 years ago they said there is nothing new under the sun.  The 20th century went from candles and horses to lightbulbs, airplanes, nuclear weapons, the moon landing and the internet.  It's comforting for some to think that everything will stay the same.  But look at the technology around you, the science around you, the new discoveries in mathematics, the globalized economy, the new ways of engaging with media and each other, new crises and new solutions.  Would you say there is nothing new under the sun?

Comment: . No I would not. There is a lot new. Most of it technologies. Not all, but the vast majority of it. The concept that theres nothing truly new is not new though. And things will change a lot from here. Meanwhile in many fields people will keep rediscovering the same things over and over.

Comment: Btw we could discover truly new things much faster if more people knew what previous people had discovered. This is not an argument to innovate slowly